# What audio file formats does WhatsApp support?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, audio-recording

What **audio** file formats does WhatsApp officially support?

I have not found this information on the WhatsApp website...

Comment: I found a workaround on YouTube to solve the 'file not supported' error in WhatsApp. Just rename the mp3 file to have an mp4 extension, and it will work.